# When to use transition vs transition-group

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, transition

I'm trying to add transitions to my form, so that when a user selects a specific answer to a question, it will dynamically show the next question. Currently I have it looking something like this:

```
<input type="text" :value="vueModel.question1" />
<div v-if="vueModel.question1 === 'hello'">
    //Do something
</div>
<div v-else-if="vueModel.question1 === 'hihi'">
    //Do something
</div>
<div v-else>
    //Do something
</div>
```

My question is, should I be adding transitions this way? (and why?)

```
<input type="text" :value="vueModel.question1" />
<transition-group name="slide-fade" mode="in-out">
    <div v-if="vueModel.question1 === 'hello'" key="key1">
        //Do something
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="vueModel.question1 === 'hihi'" key="key2">
        //Do something
    </div>
    <div v-else key="key3">
        //Do something
    </div>
</transition-group>
```

or, this way? (and why?)

```
<input type="text" :value="vueModel.question1" />
<transition name="slide-fade" mode="in-out">
    <div v-if="vueModel.question1 === 'hello'" key="key1">
        //Do something
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="vueModel.question1 === 'hihi'" key="key2">
        //Do something
    </div>
    <div v-else key="key3">
        //Do something
    </div>
</transition>
```

Or, is there another way I could do this better and which fits with Vue best practices?

Comment: we need to know you vue instance can you add it to your question?

Comment: as in what version of vue I am using? v2.5.16

Comment: It is worth to read [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)

Comment: thank you, I have read through this but I didn't find it was clear enough on when to use transition group vs transition on repeating div elements without using a v-for to loop trough them. So any guidance on that would be great! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you we have a list of items and you want to render and filter simultaneously, for example with `v-for`? In this case, you may use `transition-group` component. Unlike `transition`, this will render an actual element: like `div` in the next sniped. However, you can change the element that is rendered with the `tag` attribute.

**NOTE**

> Elements inside are always required to have a unique key attribute.

#### Update

If you just have a question and then you want to "do something" use only `transition` as in this sample.

The main difference between `transition` and `transition-group` is that transition will affect one component. This means if you have a component an you want to replaced with another component you can use transition.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-transition',
  data: {
    show: false,
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="vue-transition">
  <button @click="show = !show"> Simple Transition </button>
  <transition
    name="custom-classes-transition"
    enter-active-class="animated tada"
    leave-active-class="animated bounceOutRight"
  >
    <p v-if="show">Teocci</p>
  </transition>
</div>
```

On the other hand, `transition-group` renders an actual element from a list of elements, for that reason elements inside are always required to have a unique key attribute. For example, if you have 9 questions but you want to render a transition of each element moving randomly to another position in the **SAME** group.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#list-complete-demo',
  data: {
    items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  },
  methods: {
    shuffle: function() {
      this.items = _.shuffle(this.items)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.list-complete-item {
  transition: all 1s;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.list-complete-enter,
.list-complete-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}

.list-complete-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.1/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="list-complete-demo" class="demo">
  <button v-on:click="shuffle">Shuffle</button>
  <transition-group name="list-complete" tag="p">
    <span v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item" class="list-complete-item">
      {{ item }}
    </span>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

For that reason, if you just want to "do something" use `transition` as shown in this snippet to achieve what you want.

```js
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-selector',
  data: {
    questions: [{
        id: 0,
        description: 'Question 01',
        answer: 'hihi'
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        description: 'Question 02',
        answer: 'lala'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        description: 'Question 03',
        answer: 'hello'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        description: 'Question 04',
        answer: 'none'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        description: 'Question 05',
        answer: 'teo'
      },
    ],
    answer: {
      question: -1,
      text: '',
    },
    answerText: '',
    selected: '',
  },
  computed: {
    computedQuestions: function() {
      let vm = this;
      return this.questions.filter(function(item, index) {
        return index !== vm.answers;
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    answerQuestion: function(index) {
      this.answer.question = index;
      this.answer.text = this.answerText;
    },
    beforeEnter: function(el) {
      el.style.opacity = 0
      el.style.height = 0
    },
    enter: function(el, done) {
      var delay = el.dataset.index * 150
      setTimeout(function() {
        Velocity(
          el, {
            opacity: 1,
            height: '1.6em'
          }, {
            complete: done
          }
        )
      }, delay)
    },
    leave: function(el, done) {
      var delay = el.dataset.index * 150
      setTimeout(function() {
        Velocity(
          el, {
            opacity: 0,
            height: 0
          }, {
            complete: done
          }
        )
      }, delay)
    },
  },
});
```

```css
div.selector {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 125px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/2.0.3/velocity.min.js"></script>

<div id="vue-selector">
  <div>Question 01</div>
  <input v-model="answerText" placeholder="answer me">
  <button @click="answerQuestion(0)"> Answer </button>

  <transition name="slide-fade" mode="in-out">
    <div v-if="answer.text === 'hello'">
      Do something A
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="answer.text === 'hihi'">
      Do something B
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      Waiting for answer
    </div>
  </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't the issue I'm facing. What im not sure about is where to use the transition tags (or transition-group). My vue model is working correctly and updating the data objects as you start typing in the input field :)

Comment: ahh, sorry if you want to print multiple questions use `transition-group` for each question use `transition`

Comment: So in my example, would you recommend wrapping them all in a transition-group tag?

Comment: I updated my answer probably this example will help you. If you wrapped then all in a `transition-group` you can verify which questions will be filtered.

Comment: if I don't use a v-for for the divs, should it then change to a transition tag or still remain as a transition-group tag, with different keys on each child div?

Comment: @CRoberts, you can use both `transition` or `transition-group`. My recommendations was to use `transition-group` because I thought that you have multiple questions and you want to render some of them based on the answer of the user. However, your question is so wide and you are not clear or specific. I can find a solution using both approach but what you really want. Choose one or update your question with more information to give you a better answer.

Comment: I updated the answers using only `transition`. You don't need to use `key`. For that reason I was thinking you want to use `v-for` because it generate an `index` for each item. But if you just want to "do something" use 'transition` as per the example in my answer.

Comment: great thank you, and if I want new questions to transition in/out as my answer to the initial question changes, then I use the transition group tag to give these changing questions the animation right? :)

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, if you gonna implement a `computeQuestionList` method and render each question as part of a group that is gonna change based on the answer of the previous question, yes. But if you just want to add a sinlge question then use `transition`.